# Search for substring matches in a file bash

Tags: regex, bash

The premise is to store a database file of colon separated values representing items.

```
var1:var2:var3:var4
```

I need to sort through this file and extract the lines where any of the values match a search string.
For example

```
Search for "Help"
Hey:There:You:Friends
I:Kinda:Need:Help (this line would be extracted)
```

I'm using a function to pass in the search string, and then passing the found lines to another function to format the output. However I can't seem to be able to get the format right when passing. Here is sample code i've tried of different ways that I've found on this site, but they don't seem to be working for me

```
#Option 1, it doesn't ever find matches
function retrieveMatch {
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    while read line; do
      if [[ *"$1"* =~ "$line" ]]; then
        formatPrint "$line"
      fi
    done
  fi
}

#Option 2, it gets all the matches, but then passes the value in a
#format different than a file? At least it seems to...
function retrieveMatch {
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    formatPrint `cat database.txt | grep "$1"`
  fi
}

function formatPrint {
  list="database.txt" #default file for printing all info
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    list="$1"
  fi
  IFS=':'
  while read var1 var2 var3 var4; do
    echo "$var1"
    echo "$var2"
    echo "$var3"
    echo "$var4"
  done < "$list"
}
```

I can't seem to get the first one to find any matches
The second options gets the right values, but when I try to formatPrint, it throws an error saying that the list of values passed in are not a directory.

Comment: I think you want `"$line" =~ *"$1"*` Good luck.

Comment: you should give to the point details ( & succinct). it would be hard to find out what you need otherwise.

Comment: (1) Should matches be on full fields or partial fields?  In other words, for line `Hey:There:You:Friends I:Kinda:Need:Help`, should the string `He` match?  (2) Please show the desired sample output?  Your sample code tries to put each fields on a separate line.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I'd replace the whole thing with

```
function retrieveMatch {
  grep "$1" | tr ':' '\n'
}
```

To be called as

```
retrieveMatch Help < filename
```

...like the original function (Option 1) appeared to be designed. To do more complicated things with matching lines, have a look at awk:

```
# in the awk script, the fields in the line will be $1, $2 etc.
awk -v pattern="$1" -F : '$0 ~ pattern { for(i = 1; i < NF; ++i) print $i }'
```

See [this link](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html). Awk is made to process exactly this sort of data, so if you plan to do complex things with it, it is definitely worth a look.

Answering the question more directly, there are two/three problems in your code. One is, as was pointed out in the comments to the question, that the line

```
if [[ *"$1"* =~ "$line" ]]; then
```

Will try to use `"$line"` as a regular expression to find a match in `*"$1"*`, assuming that `*"$1"*` does not become more than one token after pathname expansion because the `*` are not quoted. Assuming that the `*` are supposed to match anything the way they would in glob expressions (but not in regular expressions), this could be replaced with

```
if [[ "$line" =~ "$1" ]]; then
```

because `=~` will report a match if the regex matches any part of the string.

The second problem is that you're divided on whether you want `"$list"` in `formatPrint` to be a file or a line. You say in `retrieveMatch` that it should be a line:

```
formatPrint "$line"
```

But you set it to a filename default in `formatPrint`:

```
list="database.txt" #default file for printing all info
```

You'll have to decide on one. If you decide that `formatPrint` should format lines, then the third problem is that the redirection in

```
while read var1 var2 var3 var4; do
  echo "$var1"
  echo "$var2"
  echo "$var3"
  echo "$var4"
done < "$list"
```

tries to use `"$list"` as a filename. This could be fixed by replacing the last line with

```
done <<< "$list" # using a here-string (bash-specific)
```

Or

```
done <<EOF
$list
EOF
```

(note: in the latter case, do not indent the code; it's a here-document that's taken verbatim). And, of course, `read` will only split four fields the way you wrote it.

Comment: You nailed it with the file/line dilemma, the cat | grep wasn't actually producing a file, so attempting to overwrite $list with the output of it, rather than a file was what was throwing errors. All good now!

Answer (score 1):

I feel I must be missing something, but..

```
cat > foo.txt
Hey:There:You:Friends I:Kinda:Need:Help
Foo:Bar
```

[Give control-D]

```
grep -i help foo.txt
Hey:There:You:Friends I:Kinda:Need:Help
```

Does it fit the bill?

EDIT: To expand a little further on this thought..

```
cat > foo.bsh
#!/bin/bash
hits="$(grep -i help foo.txt)"
while read -r line; do
    echo "${line}"
done <<< "$hits"
```

[Give control-D]